# Webpack-dev-server creates js files next to src-file instead of compiling into target bundle-file

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

About to setup a workflow with webpack for angular 2. Everything works fine so far compiling the typescript files into a target file. 
Also the webpack-dev-server runs good and autocompiles the target-file as soons as i make changes to one of the src-files.

But: It not only compiles it the target file, dev-server also creates a js file right next to the changed source-ts file. This is kinda annoying since I'd like to keep the src clean. Any Idea how to prevent this?

This is the webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [{

name: 'angular',
entry: './src/app/main.ts',
output: {
    path: './build/',
    filename: 'js/app.bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jade$/,
        loader: 'raw!jade-html'
    }, {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
    }]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
    })
]
```

}]

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Atom is the IDE of choice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You IDE could be taking over some of the compilation. Make sure you have such a line on tsconfig.json

```
"compileOnSave": false
```

Also if all your files are typescript and don't have .js files. Its a good practice to ignore *.js files in the main folder `src/app`. Add the line to you .gitignore

```
app/src/**/*.js
```